# OpenID : fail Yadis discovery on Yahoo.com with Janrain

Tags: openid, discovery, yahoo-oauth

I have the latest version of Janrain's library (v2.2.2) for OpenID.

The following endpoints will work :

- https://me.yahoo.com/user
- http://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
- http://user.myopenid.com

But if I only use "yahoo.com", it will fail. The example given with the library also fails.

Does anyone have the same issue and a fix for it ?

My implementation can be found here : http://fr.quizity.com

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you already know the answer: `yahoo.com` is not an OpenID endpoint. `me.yahoo.com` is.

There's nothing wrong with your implementation, it's just that the main site of yahoo does not contain any information about OpenID (such as location of the XRDS document).

If you're worried that your users will have a problem with understanding that, you could always make a "login with yahoo" button, eliminating the need to input an url for that provider.

Comment: Thank you Mewp ! I enventually came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like it's Yahoo's fault. There is nothing to allow discovery on yahoo.com, despite the fact that they say so in their documentation. A working url is https://me.yahoo.com but it's much less user friendly. So either they erased it by mistake, or they want us to implement a Yahoo button (rather than asking the visitor to type this ugly url). I'll still do a dirty fix on my side to redirect correctly...